# Пунктуация (запятая)

Tags: запятые

Нужна ли запятая перед «на 2 уроке»?

> Завтра(,) на 2 уроке учитель проведёт классный час.

Comment: Александр, на сайте принято благодарить участников за все полезные вопросы и ответы стрелочкой (треугольником) вверх, а также отмечать один из ответов галочкой как наиболее понравившийся и решивший проблему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сначала о втором уроке.
*Второй* — это порядковое числительное, поэтому правильно писать так:
*на **втором** уроке* (обычно числительные до десяти пишут прописью);
*на **2-м** уроке* ([по правилам наращения](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/87-rubric-99)).

Теперь о пунктуации.
Завтра (когда?), на втором уроке (когда?) — это обстоятельства времени.
Если в сопровождающем контексте вы уточняете "когда именно?", то "на втором уроке" выделяется **с двух сторон** запятыми — как уточняющий член предложения.

*Завтра, **на втором уроке,** учитель проведёт классный час.*
*Выходит, **завтра, на первом уроке,** мне придется отдуваться за всех* (О. Теряева).

Или же запятые вообще не ставятся — если по контексту уточнение не требуется.

*Завтра **на втором уроке** учитель проведёт классный час.*
*Лампудель, ты не поняла, завтра **на первом уроке** книга должна лежать на парте* (Д. Донцова).

Из [правила](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118,4):

> Если при наличии двух обстоятельств времени второе из них не служит для ограничения понятия, выраженного первым, то оно не является уточняющим и запятая между обстоятельствами не ставится: *Заседание кафедры состоится **завтра в шесть часов вечера*** (ср.: *3автра, **в шесть часов вечера,** состоится заседание кафедры*).

Comment: Никогда не понимал этот абзац у Розенталя, которым заканчивается ваш ответ. Как ни крути, но «в шесть часов» служит для ограничения «завтра». То есть запятая не ставится в предложении: «Заседание кафедры состоится завтра в шесть часов вечера» — потому, что эти обстоятельства места находятся под ударением? Проверить я это не могу, потому что других предложений таких нету в главе.

Comment: Очень много значит окружающий контекст. Вот, совершенно другое (противоположное) оформление: _**Завтра в пять часов вечера**, как обычно, великий князь выедет через западные ворота города осматривать загородные аванпосты_ (М. Строгов); _Я еду **завтра, в пять часов вечера**_ (А. Дюма).

Comment: А если такая фраза: "Вчера на втором уроке произошло ЧП"?

Comment: @Римма Михайлова, а как именно значит контекст? Какие структурные различия между контекстами предложений: «Я еду завтра, в пять часов вечера (А. Дюма)»  и «Заседание кафедры состоится завтра в шесть часов вечера»? Я не думаю, что такие различия есть. Скорее всего, у нас просто есть два способа произносить это: с паузой и бес — и эта запятая просто различает эти два способа.

Comment: В каких-то ситуациях произношение без паузы сделает речь более невыразительной, сложной к восприятию, например: «Я проснулся поздно, часу в пятом пополудни (Акс.)», «Мы отправились и бродили долго, до вечера», «Всю ночь, до петушиного рассвета, мерил Чапаев карту (Фурм.)».
В других же ситуациях отсутствие паузы допустимо и ее наличие или отсутствие является выбором говорящего: «Я еду завтра, в пять часов вечера (А. Дюма)», «Завтра, на втором уроке, учитель проведёт классный час».

Comment: Скорее всего, правильным ответом будет то, произносит ли человек эти обстоятельства времени как уточнение или выпаливает их без паузы.

Answer (score 1):

«На уроке» ограничивает «завтра» и обособляется, это серия уточняющих обстоятельств времени. Правильно будет так: «Завтра, на 2-м уроке, учитель проведёт классный час».

Answer (score 1):

**Комментарии  к двум ответам и другим комментариям**

Всё зависит **от коммуникативной ситуации** – когда, кому и зачем говорим. К примеру, надо учитывать осведомленность окружающих о происшествии, их интерес к теме. Если собеседнику (директору, например) важно узнать, что вчера произошло ЧП, то надо обособлять, «второй урок» идет на второй план как добавочная информация: ***Вчера, на втором уроке,  произошло ЧП.***

Если хотите обозначить обе координаты сразу, то не надо обособлять. Например: ***Ребята! Вчера на втором уроке у нас произошло ЧП. Давайте это обсудим.***

Так что одними правилами сложно регулировать всё, **коммуникативность** – актуальное направление в грамматике, это нельзя не учитывать, иначе **взаимное непонимание** (как в данных ответах) при чтении правил будет присутствовать постояно. Это особенно важно при анализе **разговорной речи**, сравнивать ее **с книжной речью** не всегда правильно, там свои особенности.

Можно ли использовать **однородные отношения** и перечислительную интонацию? Тоже не запрещается, это **перечисление** временных координат, хотя такой вариант встречается реже: ***Завтра, на 2 уроке // учитель проведёт классный час.***

Интонационно все три варианта прекрасно **различаются** и имеют разные семантические оттенки в каждом случае. И мы интуитивно этим пользуемся, но вот для понимания вариантов требуется хороший слух и **обобщенное понимание правил**, то есть понимание принципа выбора, а не только перечисление частных вариантов.

Также очень важна **наблюдательность**. Сейчас другое время и информационные возможности не те, что были раньше. Мы можем видеть применение теории **в реальных текстах**, да и сказал Розенталь, как мне кажется, не всё, что думал. Поэтому какая-то **коррекция правил** представляется вполне обоснованной, **жесткая регламентация** не всегда выдерживает конкуренции со стороны практического письма.

Comment: Не думаю, что может быть такая жу пунктуация, как при однородных членах, у обстоятельств времени, расположенных подряд. Непонятно, что это будет значить. Если есть два обстоятельства места, то они могут описывать обстановку, например: «Он лежал на зеленой траве, у раскидистого дуба и вспоминал молодость».

Comment: В приведенном примере  с однородными отношениями тоже описание обстановки, не вижу разницы.

Comment: Обстоятельства времени должны сообщать какое-то итоговое время. Обстоятельства времени могут быть однородными, если есть перечисление неких дат, например: «Можешь зайти завтра, послезавтра, в следующий четверг.»

Comment: Это они вам что-то должны, но не мне.